# Why my Elasticsearch query retrieves all indexed documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I've a problem to understand the functionality of the following Elasticsearch (ES 6.4) query:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "should" : [
                {
                    "match" : {
                        "title" : {
                            "query" : "example",
                            "operator" : "AND",
                            "boost" : 2
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "multi_match" : {
                        "type" : "best_fields",
                        "query" : "example",
                        "operator" : "AND",
                        "fields" : [
                            "author", "content", "tags"
                        ],
                        "boost" : 1
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must" : [
                {
                    "range" : {
                        "dateCreate" : {
                            "gte" : "2000-01-01T00:00:00+0200",
                            "lte" : "2019-02-12T23:59:59+0200"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term" : {
                        "client" : {
                            "value" : "test",
                            "boost" : 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "size" : 10,
    "from" : 0,
    "sort" : [
        {
            "_score" : {
                "order" : "desc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The query is executed successfully but retrieves about 400,000 documents which is the total count of my index. It means that all documents are in the result set. But why? Is this really the correct behavior of the multi_match query?
When I was still using the query_string query, I only got the actual matching documents. That's why I'm a bit surprised.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `minimum_should_match`:

```
    "bool" : {
        "minimum_should_match": 1,            <--- add this
        "should" : [
           ...
```

Comment: But there is `must` clause as well so the docs should be filtered based on that (unless that condition matches all the docs) even if none of the query in `should` clause matches. `minimum_should_match` would affect in a way that at least one in `should` clause should match.

Comment: Then apparently, the two must clauses match all documents as I doubt that all documents contain the `example` token. Without `minimum_should_match`, the two should clauses only serve as rank boosters.

Comment: It is so that the search term definitely does not appear in all documents, so there is something wrong with the query. I have now set minimum_should_match to 1 and get only a quarter as many results, which seems to me too much. If I set minium_should_match to 2, I can limit the result set to 4,000. But I do not quite understand the effect.

Comment: @altralaser What happens when you completely remove the `should` clause and the query has only `must` clause?

Comment: Phrased differently, how many docs do you expect with those conditions? i.e. how many did you get when you were using the `query_string` query. Also please share that query and the reason why you changed.

Comment: Ok, I restructured my query so that there is only one "must" element with "match", "multi_match", "range" and "term" as its array. I got 0 documents. Then I took the field name which I already have in the match term and put it a second time in the fields array of the multi_match. That's interesting because in this case I will now get about 5,000 documents (that seems correct). OMG!

Comment: It's probably normal that you get zero document since you only expect either the `match` or `multi_match` to return hits, so if you add them both, it's unlikely that both match at the same time. Moreover, you didn't have the `title` field in your `multi_match` query.

Comment: Ok, I understand. But why "should" gives me so many documents here?

Comment: because you don't have those clauses inside the must array, and hence, they are not required to match at all (without adding minimum_should_match)

Comment: @altralaser have you tried what I suggested in the comment above? i.e. just remove the `should` clause without any modification in `must` clause. Does this modified query also matches all the documents?

Comment: Yes, I moved all elements from "should" to "must". Please see my comment above!

Comment: @altralaser No that's not what I suggested to do. Just remove `should` clause and all its elements and leave the `must` clause as it is without any modification.

Comment: You suggest to make a query without search words?

Comment: Yes, just to check what is the output in that case.

Comment: Ok, the result is: all documents because now the term matches.